# How to create regex pattern - value between "$" character

Tags: regex, string

How to create regex pattern - value between "$" character.

e.g.
String:
" <tag key = $value$ /> "

I want get "value" string from this...

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the string between 2 `$` characters? So `ab$cdefg$hijk` would return `cdefg`? We need more information here, and your input case seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get a string that is located between 2 dollar signs. The code (perl) should look similar to:

```
if ($str =~ /\$(\w)\$/)
   $substr = $1;
```

of course, you can replace the \w sign with a pattern of your choosing...

EDIT:

```
if ($str =~ /\<tag key \= \$(\w)\$ \/\>/)
  $substr =$1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are looking to return exact word from a string.
i.e return *is* from *this island is beautiful* instead of returning *this*, *island* and *is*

If I am correct explaining your problem the regex you are looking for will be `\bis\b`

For more information visit this link, http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you could is the following:

```
var theString = '<tag key = $value$ />';

var newString = theString.replace(/^.*\$(.*?)\$.*$/, '$1');
```

Or you could use the RegExp object to do something like:

```
var pattern=new RegExp('\\$(.*?)\\$');

var newString = pattern.exec(theString )[1];
```